# Process returned -1073741819,conversion from binary to decimal

Tags: c, for-loop, binary, decimal, bit

The user is asked to input how many bits he wants and has to input also the value of every bit starting from the smallest(2^0),the program should print out the decimal value of the number given in binary by the user. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
int bit,num,dec,i;
printf("insert number of bit:");//bit 2^0 is the first one on the left
scanf("%d",&bit);
num=0;
dec=0;
for( i=0;i<bit;i++){
    printf("insert %d bit:",i+1);
    scanf("%d",num);
    dec=dec+(pow(2,i)*num);
}
printf("your number in decimal would be:%d",dec);

return 0;
}
`
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",num);` should be `scanf("%d",&num);`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Omg I'm so dumb

Comment: It's not dumb, it's a mistake. Just take note and develop an eye for this sort of mistake in the future. Additionally, enable more compiler warnings to catch these automatically.

Comment: @tadman Ignoring compiler warning is kind of .... well, never mind

Comment: And while you are at it: `scanf("%d",num);` --> `if (scanf("%d",num) != 1) exit(1);`

Comment: @4386427 Yeah i added it now,but I did it differently cause i don't know what "exit" does.

Comment: @NomeAcaso `exit` stops the program - it's used in case of serious errors